# mysql how to avoid data duplication in select request

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:
`USER: id, access_token`
`QUERIES: id, query, user_id`, user_id is a foreign key
How to make a select request to return data in the next format:
`{user_id: {[queries for this user], access_token}, ...}`

**Query**:

```
SELECT USERS.id,
       USERS.access_token,
       QUERIES.query
FROM USERS
INNER JOIN QUERIES ON USERS.id=QUERIES.user_id;
```

and I have duplicating of users.id and users.access_token. I tried to use GROUP BY to get answer as in my example but group by doesn't help

Thanks.

Comment: did you try anything? if yes then post the query.

Comment: LEFT JOIN and use alias for queries, this last help to identificate

Comment: This is just an example. it depends what you really want:
$sql = "SELECT USER.id, USER.access_token, QUERIES.id, QUERIES.query, QUERIES.user_id
FROM USER
INNER JOIN QUERIES
ON USER.id=QUERIES.id";

Comment: @fizzi thanks, your comment is helpful however it's just inner join. i modified your query: `SELECT USERS.id, USERS.access_token,  QUERIES.query FROM USERS INNER JOIN QUERIES ON USERS.id=QUERIES.user_id;` and i have duplicating of users.id and users.access_token. I tried to use GROUP BY to get answer as in my example but group by doesn't help

Comment: @rocknow add that into your question please.

Comment: @PathikVejani i think it's enough to leave it as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just how SQL works.  If you want to select from both tables in one query then you are going to get repeated data for columns from the users table.

SQL can only return a result set with the same columns for every row. So it has to put something there.

The most common way to deal with this is to loop over the data, if the user_id is the same as the previous row then don't output it to your user.

Comment: seems that you're right. I tried also `SELECT users.id, users.access_token, (SELECT query FROM queries WHERE queries.user_id = users.id) FROM users;` but get  
`ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row`